# Gnome: how to make an "desktop file ID" for xterm?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-shell

I've figured out how to run `dconf` and can edit `/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps` .  I want to add xterm to the list of apps, but I can't figure out the format to write it.  I tried just adding `'xterm.desktop'` to the list but it shows "This value is invalid for the key type."

Any ideas?

(I'm on Fedora 31 on a Thinkpad T470p.)

Answer (score 0):

dconf-editor uses [GVariant syntax](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/glib/gvariant-text.html), where an array of strings is written like this:

```
['xterm.desktop']

["xterm.desktop"]
```

An array with multiple elements would look like this:

```
['xterm.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop']
```

GVariant arrays are strongly-typed. If the array is empty, its type cannot be inferred automatically, so it must be specified like this (`as` meaning "array of string"):

```
@as []
```

Comment: OK, I've added `'xterm.desktop',` to the list in favorite-apps, and when I go to the hot corner I see an xterm icon.  Clicking it immediately returns me to the regular screen but no app starts up.  BTW assuming the startup logged an error message, do you know where they'd be logged?

Comment: In GNOME, stdout/stderr of graphical apps iš redirected to the journal (`journalctl -f`, etc). For other environments it might vary.

Comment: Thx, I'll check that out, but regardless, do you think adding `'xterm.desktop',` to the favorite-apps should have worked?  Or are there other things to do besides that?

Comment: Well, you said it _did_ work – the icon showed up in the shortcut bar, reflecting your change to the list (could've achieved the same through its right-click menu, though). Whether it _starts_ is a completely different problem.